# Local js file cannot load in springboot

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot

I write a springboot project,there is a javascript file locates at "src/main/resources/public/swagger/lib/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"

Now I want to introduce this js file in my html file,which locates at
"src/main/resources/templates/main.html"

I write `<script src='public/swagger/lib/jquery-1.8.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>` in html file

Console log:`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`
is there any wrong?

Thanks!

I think there is no wrong in my path,can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should write it with https and full link
like this `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`